# Compare different tabs columns and then pasting into another column if there's a match - Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have excel worksheet with two lists (List1 and List2) and what i want to accomplish is described bellow. I think
it's the easies way to understand. How or with what Excel funcion will complete this action?

[image]

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Q gets a simple LOOKUP for N??? What is the problem? What have you tried?

Comment: i tried this and it's not working
=VLOOKUP(A2,List2!A:B,2,FALSE)

Comment: then there is a probably a typo somewhere... because that would be the simple lookup formula (and it look correct)... pls check with `=INDEX(List2!B:B,MATCH(A2,List2!A:A,0))`... Use the "Evaluate Formula" tool at the "Formulas" tab... If the `MATCH` returns `#N/A` then there is probably something wrong with the text itself (hidden characters etc.)... simply `=A2=List2!A2` sould return `TRUE`